# Vuetify v-form post does not send data

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vuetify.js

Forgive me for the English of the Translator :)

I created a basic form to see if I get data in my API using vuetify however, when submitting the data the v-select data is not sent and I can not understand the reason, since in general the examples of these forms do not really make a request POST, follows snippets of the code I'm using:

```
<v-form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/produtos">
  <v-text-field name="escola" v-model="name" required :rules="nameRules"></v-text-field>
  <v-select
    v-model="selectPessoa"
    :items="pessoas"
    :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="nome"
    label="itens"
    required
    name="pessoa"
    return-object
    value="id"
  ></v-select>
  <v-btn color="warning" type="submit">Submit</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

Excerpt from javascript code:

```
data(){
    return { pessoas: [{ id: 1, nome: "sandro" },
                       { id: 2, nome: "haiden" }], 
             name: '',
             selectPessoa: null,
    }
}
```

The information I type in the v-text-field I get in the API node, but the one in the v-select does not:

Form screen:
[image]

API log screen:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the`<v-select>` component you have defined the `return-object` and `item-value="id"` props. Using the return-object is overriding the item-value by returning the entire object from the v-select component instead of just the id. In this case you could just remove the `return-object` prop from the `<v-select>` component and that will fix your issue.

```
<v-select
  v-model="selectPessoa"
  :items="pessoas"
  :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
  item-value="id"
  item-text="nome"
  label="itens"
  required
  name="pessoa"
  return-object <------REMOVE THIS!!!
  value="id"
></v-select>
```

Vuetify v-select docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects
[image: image of vuetify docs]

Another option instead of removing the return-object prop could be to modify your API endpoint to expect an object rather than an int.

Also, I would not recommend using the "method" and "action" attributes on the `<v-form>` component. Instead, put a click event handler on the submit button of the form that calls a method. The method should then grab the data and send it to the API endpoint via an AJAX call.

On the Form Component

Before: `<v-form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/produtos">`

After: `<form @submit.prevent>`

On the Button Component

Before: `<v-btn color="warning" type="submit">Submit</v-btn>`

After: `<v-btn color="warning" @click="submit">Submit</v-btn>`

In the methods have a function do something like this (used axios in my example, not sure what your project is using):

```
methods: {
  submit () {
    let data = { name: this.name, selectPessoa: this.selectPessoa }
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/produtos', data)
    .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```